# Kendo (WYSIWYG) Editor doesn`t send <form> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I use Kendo Editor on my website, but I have problem. I want to fill in embedded form code from MailChimp but Editor remove the form tag.
I don't know how should I make it work. I have read a documentation but there is no solution.
Thanks for advice

Comment: Post some code, we can't help you with the very limited description you have given. Just remember to replace any API keys or passwords with "XXXX".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kendo will automatically decode the html tag inside.
Thus you need to encode the value of editor. Please check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5eav9/

Try to put this value in the editor:

```
<form><p>Hello world!!</p></form>
```

Then click the button, you will get:

```
&lt;form&gt;&lt;p&gt;Hello world!!&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/form&gt;
```

then, call encode function,

```
Encoder.htmlDecode(editor.value())
```

you will get:

```
<form><p>Hello world!!</p></form>
```

Note: I used external js http://www.strictly-software.com/scripts/downloads/encoder.js to encode the html tag.

Comment: Just replace both `alerts` with `$("form>p").text(editor.value());` and everything from Kendo will go to form.